# Is there a way to speed up videos on a website (not Youtube, or any of the main platforms)

Tags: video, video-processing

Had some questions regarding video speed.

I have some videos for classes that I am taking that are way too slow in speed. I have tried downloading a number of extensions to speed up playback (on chrome) but nothing has worked as of yet.

Does anyone have a script I could use or know of any extensions that might work?

Please let me know.

Also, if you can speed up the playback on this:
https://body.io/ask-kiefer-anything-unfiltered-session-2-transgender-athletes/

That'd be great :)

Comment: Not sure I'm following correctly—but are you referring to delivery of video content to end users? A lot on that depends upon your Web server capability, and why even larger sites use third-party services such as a CDN or video streaming service for this.

Comment: No, I am end user and need to speed up the video playback for my consumption.